# Angular : add and Change class by clicking on button

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm starting to study Angular. But I got some troubles and i need your knowledge. How can I do to up or down the number of my variable "loveIts" contains into my array "arrayPost" when I click on my buttons ?

Then, when I up or down my number, what I need to do to change my [ngClass] ? I have been already prepared my function "btnLove" et "btnNotLove".

#### app.component.html :

```
<h2>{{mainTitle}}</h2>
<ul class="list-group">
  <app-post *ngFor="let i of arrayPost"
  [postLoveIts]="i.loveIts"></app-post>
</ul>
```

#### app.component.ts :

```
arrayPost = [
    {
      loveIts: -1,
    },
    {
      loveIts: 1,
    },
    {
      loveIts: 0,
    }
  ];
```

#### post.component.html :

```
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item': true,
                'list-group-item-danger': postLoveIts < 0,
                'list-group-item-success': postLoveIts > 0}">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="btnLove">Love it !</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="btnNotLove">Don't love it !</button>

</li>
```

#### post.component.ts :

```
  @Input() postLoveIts: number;

  btnLove() {

  }

  btnNotLove() {

  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It looks that you have everything you need

Comment: [tag:angularjs] is not the same as [tag:angular] which is what your question is about. I removed the former from the tag list.

Comment: I don't know what I need to write in my function "btnLove" et "btnNotLove" when they are clicked. How change my number and how change the class of my <il> tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your problem, but my intuition says that you want this piece of code

```
<li class="list-group-item" 
    [class.list-group-item-danger]="postLoveIts < 0"
    [class.list-group-item-success]="postLoveIts > 0"
```